# increase the "words choice list" froms 6 to 9?

Tags: ibus

I am using ibus-quick ime. 
The words choice show only 6 words st once instead of 9 in window.
This make the typing experience differ a lot as people are used to the old word choice( and this is not a good reason to change.)

Is there any way to improve the "words choice list" froms 6 to 9?

Comment: ok i found the answer of it.

$sudo gedit /usr/share/ibus-table/engine/table.py

search _page_size , change from 6 to 9

Comment: Could you please write your comment as an answer and then accept it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*(OP solved issue)*

ok i found the answer of it. `$sudo gedit /usr/share/ibus-table/engine/table.py` search for `_page_size` , change it from 6 to 9 – user998661 Jan 17 at 15:36